# Connecting to SQL Server database with Mono C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, mono

I am trying to migrate my service cross-platform with mono, but in attempting to connect to a SQL Server database I get the following timeout error

> Timeout expired. The timeout period elapsed prior to the completion of the operation or the server is not responding. at Mono.Data.Tds.Protocol.TdsComm..ctor
>
> ```
>   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open()
> ```

Databases are fairly new to me, but as far as I can tell from [here](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache%3aEHgvy4ZWB-AJ%3awww.mono-project.com/ADO.NET%20ado.net&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&source=www.google.com) (Google cache page, mono site is down) accessing SQL Server databases is now possible in Mono. Is that correct?

I attempted to structure my connection string as shown, but still no luck. My simple test code...

```
using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(cs))

            {

                con.Open();

                SqlDataReader reader = null;

                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT Parameter FROM Deltas", con);

                reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

                reader.Read();

                    Console.WriteLine(reader["Parameter"].ToString());

                con.Close();

            }
```

Am I missing any references or is my format incorrect? How can I connect using Mono C#?

EDIT:

Connection String, Defined globally and init in constuctor:

```
         cs = @"Server=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx;
               Database=myDB;
               User ID=user;
               Password=passwd;";


     cs = @"Data Source=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx;
               Network Library=DBMSSOCN;
               Initial Catalog=myDB;
               User ID=user;
               Password=passwd;";
```

Top is me trying to conform to the mono example, bottom is what works with the .NET runtime.

Comment: Where is the connection string defined? And what does it look like?

Comment: @Oded - Sorry about that, see my edit.

Comment: @peer -  could you elabourate? The error is as above, a timeout error it seems.

Comment: does you sqlserver allow remote connections and is the firewall configured for allowing connections?

Comment: @peer - yeap, I am fully connected via .NET, it seems I am doing something mono does not like however.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you hit a bug:

http://www.mail-archive.com/mono-bugs@lists.ximian.com/msg50686.html

quote:

> This only happens when using the .NET 2.0 version of TdsComm - when
>   compiling with .NET 1.0 (mcs instead of gmcs), the connection also
>   works.

Comment: thanks peer, could you help me interpret this a litte, he says compiling with .NET 1.0 works, but not 2.0. Is there an alternative to get this working with 3.5?

Comment: the logs show that the bug was resolved in 2008, do you run the latest version of mono?

Comment: Yeah, I am using 2.10.2. The problem seems to be the connection string?

Comment: You can try to fix the dns lookup, it cannot do the reverse lookup (see description of the bug). If the Dns.GetHostEntry() works it should work fine.

Comment: Hmmm, I have never edited the source code of a library before, im not sure what would be required of me in this case. How can I locate the dll? I would need to distribute the altered file also? Was the patch not fixed with his commit? Should I try using an earlier version of mono instead? see here: http://go-mono.com/forums/#nabble-td3482638

Comment: It seems someone reintroduced the 2008 bug. You can try one earlier version or compile for 1.0 (which is a little old).

Comment: ok cheers, I will check and see if an earlier version helps so

Comment: It seems I am connected! (with cautious optimism :P) much appreciated!

Comment: I should mention I am using the latest long term supported version of mono, 2.6.7.